# React, show loading component inside navbar until data is fetched

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a navbar component that I pass options to it. One of these options is the title for menus. It used to be string but now one of the titles is the username so I have to pass a dynamic value which is fetched later.

I wanted to show a loading animation until it is fetched. So I pass this `Loading` component as username until the `userName` is fully fetched. How can I achieve this the right way? Here is a simplified version of my code:

App:

```
const App = () => {
  const [userName, setUserName] = useState(Loading);

  // fetching userName
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({
        userName: "YSLdev"
      }),
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
      }
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
        setUserName(json.userName);
      });
  }, []);

  // setting options to be shown in navbar
  const navBarOptions = [
    {
      name: userName,
      icon: "fingerprint",
      menuItems: [
        {
          href: "/camera",
          icon: "videocam",
          description: "Camera"
        },
        {
          href: "/data-analytics",
          icon: "stacked_bar_chart",
          description: "Data Analysis"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "Tools",
      icon: "settings",
      menuItems: [
        {
          href: "#",
          icon: "navigation",
          description: "Top View"
        },
        {
          href: "#",
          icon: "filter_alt",
          description: "Display Human"
        }
      ]
    }
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      <NavBar options={navBarOptions} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

NavBar:

```
import React from "react";
import styles from "./navbar.module.scss";

export default function NavBar({ options }) {
  return (
    <div className={styles["navbar"]}>
      {options &&
        options.map((option, index) => (
          <div key={index} className={styles["option"]}>
            <div className={`${styles["icon"]} material-icons`}>
              {option.icon}
            </div>
            <div className={styles["title"]}>{option.name}</div>
            <div className={styles["menu"]}>
              {option.menuItems.map((item, i) => (
                <div key={i}>{item.description}</div>
                // ... other tags
              ))}
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Loading:

```
export default function Loading({ size = "small" }) {
  switch (size) {
    case "small":
      return (
        <div className={styles["loadingio-spinner-spinner-5dnhr28eat2"]}>
          <div className={styles["ldio-53fz0lrw47f"]}>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    case "medium":
      return (
        <div className={styles["loadingio-spinner-spinner-8vfig2z3vf"]}>
          <div className={styles["ldio-w7mnwgpb5e"]}>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    default:
      return (
        <div className={styles["loadingio-spinner-spinner-8vfig2z3vf"]}>
          <div className={styles["ldio-w7mnwgpb5e"]}>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: You can't pass a React component as parameter. What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: @yousoumar Until it's fully fetched, I would like to show a loading animation where userName is going to be shown.

Comment: @yousoumar React functional components are just functions returning JSX so basically you can use them as values however you want. Seems like the problem was with "not executing the function". This fixed the problem because now I can send props to the function and also get the returned JSX and render them

Comment: I was talking about passing a component to `useState`, first time I'm seeing this.

Comment: @yousoumar is correct. The state is not typically used to hold components

Comment: @yousoumar I have a navbar component that I pass options to it. One of these options is the title for menus. It used to be string but now one of the titles is the username so I have to pass a dynamic value which is fetched later. I wanted to show a loading animation until it is fetched. So I pass this component as username until the userName is fully fetched. You are right it does seem incorrect. How can I make it better?

Comment: I see @YSLdev. Can you edit the question so we have a bigger view, at least the component that's fetching the data, the navbar and how they are tied together? You can use this [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nextjs-5tlgz) to even make it a fully working example, with a fake api like [JSONPlaceholder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com).

Comment: @yousoumar Of course. The actual component is very large and I'm not allowed to share  it. But here is the [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/next-js-forked-fbq7jj). This is a very simplified example of what I wanted to implement

Comment: Thanks @YSLdev. I pasted an answer.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to achieve what you want is to change your `useState` part to below code, as it's not correct to pass a component as parameter to it:

```
const [userName, setUserName] = useState("");
```

And change the `userName` object in `navBarOptions` array to this:

```
{
   name: userName ? userName : <Loading size="small" />,
  icon: "fingerprint",
  menuItems: [
    {
      href: "/camera",
      icon: "videocam",
      description: "Camera"
    },
    {
      href: "/data-analytics",
      icon: "stacked_bar_chart",
      description: "Data Analysis"
    }
  ] 
},
```

Forked  working code here on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/next-js-forked-kmxsq9?file=/index.js:773-1137).

Answer (score 0):

You must define a boolean state. and set it to *true* before sending a request to the api. And after getting the response, change it to *false*:

```
// if initial value set to true, you don't need to set it to true before send request to api
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({
            userName: "YSLdev"
        }),
        headers: {
          "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
        }
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
          setUserName(json.userName);
      })
      .finally(() => {
          setLoading(false);
      });
  }, []);
```

then you can use `loading` state for conditional rendering.